# Feedforward Control for Underactuated Systems: Linear Control Theory

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control

I have an underactuated mechanical system (linear bicycle model of a vehicle). I have two outputs that have to be controlled to zero and one input (you guessed it - steer angle, $\delta$). I have three exogeneous inputs, represented by $d_i$s. Following is the general structure of the state space for the error dynamics

$\begin{pmatrix}
\dot{e}_1 \\
\dot{e}_2 \\
\dot{e}_3 \\
\dot{e}_4 \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & p_1 & p_2 & p_3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & p_4 & p_5 & p_6 \\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
e_1 \\
e_2 \\
e_3 \\
e_4 \\
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
b_1 \\
0 \\
b_2 \\
\end{pmatrix} \delta + \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
q_1 & q_2 & q_3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & q_4 & q_5 \\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
d_1 \\
d_2 \\
d_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

As can be seen, for feedforward control design, I have two error dynamics, $\dot{e}_2$ and $\dot{e}_4$, that need to go to $0$ asymptotically. But with one input, $\delta$, I can only choose it such that one of them can be tackled. What I mean is

$\delta = \delta_{fb} + \delta_{ff}$

I can choose $(\delta_{ff} = - q_1 \cdot d_1 - q_2 \cdot d_2 - q_3 \cdot d_3)$ or $(\delta_{ff} = - q_4 \cdot d_2 - q_5 \cdot d_3)$. i.e. to say I cannot select $\delta$ to satisfy both requirements. This is to say the system is underactuated. How can we deal with such a requirement?

Any reference source would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term _exogeneous input_, are these simply disturbances?

Comment: Like disturbances they are not under our control but unlike them it is not really a disturbance in its literal sense. Like in case of a car, if you look at a moving vehicle in front of you and you measure its position, it is a function of both your states and states of the vehicle you are looking at. Now the states of the vehicle are not in your control but they definitely affect your measurements. You can take them as disturbances but they are inputs to the model you know well about but cannot control it

Comment: As a general reference, I recommend the online textbook [Underactuated Robotics](http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/underactuated.html). As to your specific case, I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for: are you looking for a feedforward solution, with a known trajectory for $d_i$, or a feedback controller, or MPC? Is there a reason a straightforward LQR wouldn't work? There are many possible approaches... or are you unsure what's out there and asking for a general overview?

Comment: Thanks and I'll go through it...as you can see by dividing the control input into feedback and feed forward, I can easily design feedback if the system is controllable. That's not the issue. The issue is with design of a feed forward given known disturbances d. As you can see I have one input signal and two states that depend on disturbances.

Comment: Do $d_i$ depend on the state? Or are they a fixed time-dependent trajectory? Is the latter, why not just formulate it as a quadratic (or linear, or whatever other convex) optimisation problem?

Comment: You can think that the problem constitutes of two systems. Lets call it $S_1$ and $S_2$. Let the states be $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ for $S_1$ and $(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$ for $S_2$. I control $S_1$. Note that these two systems are exactly same. So I know ($z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$) at all time. For $S_1$, i give error dynamics as you see in the question where the states $d_i \in (z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$. So I know $d_i$ completely at all times. They are time varying. How do you plan to get feedforward control by using convex optimization? I can think of some ways of writing it but they dont seem convincing to me

Comment: What I mean by fixed trajectory is, do you know $d_i$ at all times, already at time $t=0$? Or do you mean that you can directly measure each $z_i$ and therefore know $d_i$ at each time?  
Now, if $S_2$ is a known system, why can't you simply model it and include it as additional states to your controlled system? The only reason I can think of is that there must be something unknown about it, such as it has it's own controller, the model of which we do not know...?

Comment: The $d_i$s are communicated over wireless network. It has certain delays and uncertainties that need to be modeled later. That's one reason of not including it as states because it would affect the feedback loop and hence the stability of the system. So if I loose communication nothing would work. Second reason is writing it like this allows me to write the error dynamics in a nice and clean form as you see in the question and the errors can be measured using sensors. Hence I can guarantee a basic performance. The feed forward adds to the performance.

Comment: So... use an estimate of the expected $d_i$ in your system dynamics to do feedforward, and then handle the uncertainties with feedback. I'm still confused what the actual problem is, and why the standard approaches aren't satisfactory. I'm happy to discuss it further, but since the comments are getting longer than the question, feel free to contact me directly at heim.steve [at] gmail.com